# Исправить функцию вывода

Tags: php

1. с помощью $js=file_get_contents получаю данные со стороннего сайта - title
2. далее, полученный title отправляю в поиск
3. получаю результат поиска

Проблема в том, что функция получив в ответ $js=file_get_contents 
2 и более title использует один и по нему выдает результат.

То есть, если в админке я создал 5 блоков (вывидет 5 блоков с результатами на мой сайт)
то $js=file_get_contents будет обработана 5 раз, из-за чего несколько блоков на сайте могут быть одинаковыми,
так как результы выполнения пяти $js=file_get_contents частично могут быть одинаковыми (получим 5 title, 2 или 3 из которых могут быть идентичны),
следовательно и на сайте будут повторы.

Как переписать или исправить мою функцию так, чтобы $js=file_get_contents
выполнялась один раз и выводила столько блоков на сайте, сколько title было получено?

title ставится в поиск в строке $this->url   ---   q=".urlencode($itemtitle)."

Помогите пожалуйста, очень надо но я не осилю 100%   :(

```
 protected function getcates($nom){

 $part = "snippet"; 

 $js=file_get_contents('сайт.ру/script.js'); 
 if(preg_match('#push\((?<json>.*?)\);#',$js,$match)){
 $wares=json_decode($match['json'])->wares;
 foreach ($wares as $item) {

 $itemtitle = $item->title;
 $itemtitle = preg_replace('/[^\p{L}0-9 \!]/iu', ' ', $itemtitle);

 }
 } 

 $this->url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key={$this->config["key"]}&part=$part&order=date&maxResults=4&q=".urlencode($itemtitle)."&videoEmbeddable=true&videoSyndicated=true&type=video"; 
 $data = $this->http(TRUE);
 $html = "";
 foreach ($data->items as $yt) {
     $html .= "РЕЗУЛЬТАТ РАБОТЫ ФУНКЦИИ {$yt->id->videoId}{$yt->snippet->title}";
 }

     if(!empty($html)){

     $html = 'шапка блока'.$html.'футер блока';

     }

 return $html; 
     }
```

Спасибо!

```
protected function getcates($nom){ 

$part = "snippet"; 

$js=file_get_contents('сайт.ру//…'); 
if(preg_match('#push\((?<json>.*?)\);#',$js,$match)){ 
$wares=json_decode($match['json'])->wares; 
$titles = []; 
foreach ($wares as $item) { 
$itemtitle = $item->title; 
$itemtitle = preg_replace('/[^\p{L}0-9 \!]/iu', ' ', $itemtitle); 
$titles[] = $itemtitle; 
} 
} 
//$html = ""; 
foreach ($titles as $itemtitle) { 
$this->url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key={$this->config["key"]}&part=$part&order=date&maxResults=4&q=".urlencode($itemtitle)."&videoEmbeddable=true&videoSyndicated=true&type=video"; 
$data = $this->http(TRUE); 
$html = ""; 
foreach ($data->items as $yt) { 
$html .= "РЕЗУЛЬТАТ РАБОТЫ ФУНКЦИИ {$yt->id->videoId}{$yt->snippet->title}"; 
} 
} 

if(!empty($html)){ 

$html = 'шапка блока'.$html.'футер блока'; 

} 
return $html; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас проблема в бесполезном цикле:

```
foreach ($wares as $item) {
 $itemtitle = $item->title;
 $itemtitle = preg_replace('/[^\p{L}0-9 \!]/iu', ' ', $itemtitle);
}
```

Обрабатывается только последний `title`.

Нужно весь код по обработке этого `title` добавить внутрь цикла, либо собрать их в массив и потом итерировать.

Например, так:

```
$titles = [];
foreach ($wares as $item) {
 $itemtitle = $item->title;
 $itemtitle = preg_replace('/[^\p{L}0-9 \!]/iu', ' ', $itemtitle);
 $titles[] = $itemtitle;
}
```

И ниже итерируете заголовки и строите нужные блоки:

```
$html = "";
foreach ($titles as $itemtitle) {
  $this->url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key={$this->config["key"]}&part=$part&order=date&maxResults=4&q=".urlencode($itemtitle)."&videoEmbeddable=true&videoSyndicated=true&type=video"; 
  $html .= "...";
  // ...
}
```

*Думаю очевидно, что в этом конкретном случае можно не собирать массив, а генерировать блоки прямо в первом цикле.*

Comment: Ну, если работает - чего проверять? =) Комментарии - плохое место для кода.

Comment: Нет, у вас ничего не должно было измениться) Минутку

Comment: vp_arth, СПАСИБО! Теперь вроде понял   :)

Comment: Вызывающий код я не видел, теперь не нужно вызывать эту функцию многократно...

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54807/discussion-between-microru-and-vp-arth).

Comment: vp_arth, в вопрос добавил код, где закомментировал //$html = ""; проверьте, пожалуйста. Очень долго страница грузится, повторов вроде нет.

Comment: Хотя и повторы тоже есть   :(